# Parse RSS with AppleScript (using grep?)

Tags: macos, rss, applescript

I am trying to write an AppleScript to set my desktop background to the most recent NASA image of the day. I am trying to do this using this RSS feed: https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/lg_image_of_the_day.rss

The last piece of the puzzle is parsing the URL of the image from the rss feed. I assume this should be very possible using grep, but I don't know how to use grep. I did look through the feed, and I know that the URL I want will be the first `<link>` in the first `<item>`.

```
set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to (current date)

set todaydate to d & "\\ " & m & "\\ " & y
log todaydate

set myFile to "/Users/me/Pictures/NASA\\ Image\\ of\\ the\\ Day/" & todaydate & ".jpg"

property RSSURL : "https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/lg_image_of_the_day.rss"

--get the first download link from the rss feed
--ie stuff inside <link> </link> directly after first <item>

set pictureURL to "" --but to the right thing, of course

do shell script "curl -o " & myFile & " " & pictureURL

tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "myFile"
```

Comment: Grepping markup is nasty and wrong. See System Events' XML Suite: you should be able to extract the relevant value with a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victory!!

```
set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to (current date)

set todaydate to d & "_" & m & "_" & y
log todaydate

set dir to "~/Pictures/NASA_image_of_the_day/"

set myFile to dir & todaydate & ".jpg"

property RSSURL : "https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/lg_image_of_the_day.rss"

set XMLfile to dir & "feed.xml"
do shell script "curl -o " & XMLfile & " " & RSSURL

tell application "System Events"
    tell XML file XMLfile
        tell XML element "rss"
            tell XML element "channel"
                tell XML element "item"
                    tell XML element "enclosure"
                        set pictureURL to value of XML attribute "url"
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

--display dialog pictureURL
--display dialog myFile

do shell script "curl -o " & myFile & " " & pictureURL & " -L"

tell application "System Events"
    tell every desktop
        set picture to myFile
    end tell
end tell
```